# How to use logical OR in find?

Tags: find, ls, patterns

In bash shell `ls` can use a logical OR functionality through (of course I could also do `ls name1 name2` but my true examples are more complicated):

```
ls @(name1|name2)
```

Is there a way to do this using `find`?

My naive implementation:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name @("name1"|"name2")
```

doesn't work (it just outputs nothing)

Comment: Did you read the `OPERATORS` section of the `find` manpage?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use `-o` for logical `OR`.  Beware however that all `find` predicates have logical values, so you'll usually need to group `OR`ed things together with parens.  And since parens also have a meaning to the shell, you'll also need to escape them:

```
find /some/dir -maxdepth 1 \( -name '*.c' -o -name '*.h' \) -print
```

Answer (score 10):

To answer your question, you can use `-o` option:

```
   expr1 -o expr2
          Or; expr2 is not evaluated if expr1 is true.

   expr1 -or expr2
          Same as expr1 -o expr2, but not POSIX compliant.
```

like this:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -name "name1" -o -name "name2"
./name1
./name2
```